# Google Cloud Functions googleapiclient.discovery.build() takes a long time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

To make use of Google ML Engine, I have the following two lines in my Google Cloud Function before I send predictions to my models with the recommended `predict_json()` function:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
service = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', cache_discovery=False)
```

Creating this service occasionally takes long (~6-7 seconds), however, the underlying mechanism is a simple HTTP request! I see the following log:

```
URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/ml/v1/rest
```

I have looked through other posts in Stack Overflow and read related issues in GitHub including this one: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/325. I tried creating my own cache object and passing it to the `cache` argument, and passing `True` to the `cache_discovery` argument. However, none of these worked. Specifically, the latter attempt results in a known error within Google Cloud API.

I need to decrease the run-time of the function, and would greatly appreciate if you have any ideas, suggestions, and comments. Thanks!

**Edit:** I am attaching a screenshot of logs as suggested:
[image: Screenshot of Logs]

Comment: I suggest editing the question to add the code that you used to benchmark the specific lines of code that you think are taking longer than you'd like.

Comment: Hi Doug, I am not sure I understood that. Do you mean adding the codes for the other approaches I tried? The line above _is_ the line that takes longer.

Comment: So, how do you know that for sure?  How did you measure it?

Comment: Through the logs in Google Cloud Functions. This is the first line in my function. I can see the time the function is called, and I see that the log I displayed above shows up after ~6-7 seconds.

Comment: The cloud functions logs don't show line-level durations.  What you're seeing is how long the entire function took to execute.  There is also the factor of the time it takes to cold start a function, which will skew those timings.  I have a hard time imagining these are the only lines in your function.  It will be helpful to see how you measure the breakdown of each line of code, so anyone can reproduce your specific case.

Comment: Nope, they don't you are right. You can always have print statements though. I made the time calculation based on the `INFO` message on the logs. I will attach a screenshot above. Of course, those are not the only lines included; but this is where the lost time takes place as seen from logs. On the other hand, please tell me more about the cold start issue. If memory serves me correct, there is no way to get rid of it in Google Cloud Functions right?

Comment: To be clear, are you calling `build()` _inside_ your function, or outside it, but at the top of the file before the function is defined?

Comment: I call it outside the function, at top of the file.

Comment: Calling the `build()` method dos not take long in my case. Maybe the issue is someplace else. Could you share what other actions are taken in your function?